# Self triggered SQS requests on dev - Why?

Tags: amazon-sqs, homestead, laravel-5.7

I recently updated to latest laravel v5.7.9, on my dev Homestead.

I'm not using queues in my project. `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`, I have never touched file `\app\Console\Kernel.php` and never configured `SQS` in `.env`.

But Now I'm getting file `worker.log` in my project root. It is always empty.

Plus.

My Laravel.log file is getting too big for no reason. Yesterday was Sunday, I did not even switch on my Notebook (Windows 10, it may switch on by itself).

Today, I switched my computer on and find 8 Mb of a log file.
First line was 8.752.288 entities of the special character `null`, 
then it was

```
...[2018-10-14 22:07:41] local.ERROR: Error executing "ReceiveMessage" on "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
```

the 403 is reasonable, I don't have SQS configured, but why did it started sending something to AWS at 10 pm on Sunday, from my dev homestead?

the last record in the log was dated on [2018-10-14 22:09:27] and it did not continue triggering this stuff on Monday when I started my computer.

**Please Help**

***Please find full log record below:****

```
2018-10-14 22:07:41] local.ERROR: Error executing "ReceiveMessage" on "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>I (truncated...)
 InvalidClientTokenId (client): The security token included in the request is invalid. - <?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code><Message>The security token included in the request is invalid.</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId> blah - blah - blah </RequestId></ErrorResponse> {"exception":"[object] (Aws\\Sqs\\Exception\\SqsException(code: 0): Error executing \"ReceiveMessage\" on \"https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name\"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><ErrorResponse xmlns=\"http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/\"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>I (truncated...)
 InvalidClientTokenId (client): The security token included in the request is invalid. - <?xml version=\"1.0\"?><ErrorResponse xmlns=\"http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/\"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code><Message>The security token included in the request is invalid.</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId>blah - blah - blah</RequestId></ErrorResponse> at /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php:191, GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException(code: 403): Client error: `POST https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><ErrorResponse xmlns=\"http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/\"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>I (truncated...)
 at /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php(100): Aws\\WrappedHttpHandler->parseError(Array, Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Object(Aws\\Command), Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): Aws\\WrappedHttpHandler->Aws\\{closure}(Array)
#2 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(174): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise::callHandler(2, Array, Array)
#3 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/RejectedPromise.php(40): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise::GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\{closure}(Array)
#4 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\RejectedPromise::GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\{closure}()
#5 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php(98): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\TaskQueue->run()
#6 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php(125): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlMultiHandler->tick()
#7 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(246): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlMultiHandler->execute(true)
#8 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(223): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise->invokeWaitFn()
#9 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(267): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise->waitIfPending()
#10 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(225): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise->invokeWaitList()
#11 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(267): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise->waitIfPending()
#12 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(225): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise->invokeWaitList()
#13 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise->waitIfPending()
#14 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClientTrait.php(58): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise->wait()
#15 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClientTrait.php(77): Aws\\AwsClient->execute(Object(Aws\\Command))
#16 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SqsQueue.php(120): Aws\\AwsClient->__call('receiveMessage', Array)
#17 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(247): Illuminate\\Queue\\SqsQueue->pop('https://sqs.us-...')
#18 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(107): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->getNextJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\SqsQueue), 'your-queue-name')
#19 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(102): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('sqs', 'your-queue-name', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#20 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(86): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('sqs', 'your-queue-name')
#21 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#22 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#24 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#25 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(572): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#26 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#27 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#28 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#29 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(886): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#30 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(262): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#31 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(145): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#32 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(89): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#33 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#35 {main}
"} 
[2018-10-14 22:07:43] local.ERROR: Error executing "ReceiveMessage" on "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
```

Comment: I also asked it here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was Supervisor. problem solved by the command:

```
$ sudo supervisorctl stop all
```

more infore [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration)